# Looping across 10 columns at a time in R

Tags: r, traminer, sequence-alignment

I have a dataframe with 1000 columns. I am trying to loop over 10 columns at a time and use the `seqdef()` function from the `TraMineR` package to do sequence alignment across the data in those columns. Hence, I want to apply this function to columns 1-10 in the first go-around, and columns 11-20 in the second go-around, all the way up to 1000.

This is the code I am using.

```
library(TraMineR)
by(df[, 1:10], seqdef(df))
```

However, this only loops over the first 10 and then stops. How do I loop it across chunks of 10 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this using `mapply` and setting the sequence of columns to loop across.

```
colpicks <- seq(10,1000,by=10)
mapply(function(start,stop) seqdef(df[,start:stop]), colpicks-9, colpicks)
```

Comment: Thanks - and if I want to save the output of each run (i.e. 100 runs in total) to a separate object named by run (i.e. object1, object2, etc.) - how can I add this to the code?

Comment: @histelheim - I think the above output should give you a list (I'm not sure what `seqdef` does). If you save the output like `result <- mapply(...` you can access each object like `result[1]` `result[2]` etc. It's generally discouraged to have a massive number of similar objects when they are better stored in a single list.