# sum k columns of a matrix at a time

Tags: r

I have a matrix/ dataframe that I wish to add k columns at a time. However, the twist is that the number of columns is not a multiple of k. Below is an example where k=5.

```
set.seed(1)
m=matrix(rnorm(7*12),nrow = 7)
col_group=1:5
ncol_agg = ceiling(dim(m)[2]/length(col_group))
a=matrix(nrow=dim(m)[1],ncol=ncol_agg)
for (i in 1:ncol_agg){
  cols = col_group+(i-1)*length(col_group)
  if (cols[length(cols)]>dim(m)[2])
    cols = cols[1]:dim(m)[2]
  a[,i] = rowSums(m[,cols])
}
```

The closes answer I could find was (
from: [Looping across 10 columns at a time in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672468/looping-across-10-columns-at-a-time-in-r))

```
k=5
colpicks <- seq(k,dim(m)[2],by=k)
mapply(function(start,stop) rowSums(m[,start:stop]), colpicks-k, colpicks)
```

but this will only give me up until the last multiple of 5, i.e. does not sum the remaining 2 columns (11th and 12th columns) in `m`.

Whats the most efficient way to do this operation without losing the last column of `a`.

Comment: you could use `starts <- which(1:12 %% k == 1); stops <- unique(c(which(1:12 %% k == 0), ncol(m)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could edit my original answer to change the `colpicks` variable. E.g.:

```
k <- 5
starts <- seq(1, ncol(m), k) 
stops  <- c(tail(starts - 1, -1), ncol(m) )
starts
#[1]  1  6 11
stops
#[1]  5 10 12
mapply(function(start,stop) rowSums(m[,start:stop]), starts, stops)

#          [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
#[1,]  1.540788  0.8238572  0.47661488
#[2,]  1.206998 -1.2269287 -0.63560511
#[3,] -1.787879 -0.6015836  0.02120541
#[4,]  4.567936 -1.2063633 -1.50276636
#[5,]  1.872115  3.8655672 -1.38881202
#[6,] -1.057408  2.1510464  1.46953323
#[7,] -3.656105  4.4770430 -1.96685867
```

Comment: you don't need the unique() function do you? The last element of `stops` will always be `ncol(m)` and `starts-1` will never have the element `ncol(m)`